# How to write a bash script to label each argument like this:

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

```
$ bash argcnt.sh this is a "real live" test
is
real live
```

(to display only paired arguments)

Because, I know only in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$2"
echo "$4"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "_label each argument_"? What label? And why "_each_" if you want to print every other argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to print every other argument given to the script. You could then create a loop over `$@`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# idx will be 2, 4, 6 ... for as long as it's less than the number of arguments given
for ((idx = 2; idx < ${#@}; idx += 2))
do
    # variable indirection below:
    echo "${!idx}"
done
```

Note: You can use `$#` instead of `${#@}` to get the number of elements in `$@` too. I don't know which one that is preferred by people in general.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is print every other argument, starting from the second, you can use `shift`:

```sh
$ cat argcnt
#!/bin/bash
while shift; do printf '%s\n' "$1"; shift; done

$ ./argcnt this is a "real live" test foo
is
real live
foo
```